# ice40 UltraPlus Mobile Development Platform

Tags: fpga, lattice, ice40

I have a Lattice iCE40 UltraPlus Mobile Development Platform, new piece ordered from Digikey. This has 4 iCE40 UltraPlus devices (iCE40UP5K-UWG30)

I have compiled the icestorm suite, and ran the "rgb.v" example in "icestorm/examples/up5k_rgb" as follows.

```
$ make -f Makefile.uwg30 prog
iceprog -S rgb.bin
init..
cdone: high
reset..
cdone: high
programming..
cdone: high
Bye.
$
```

I have followed the "User Guide" to set jumpers etc. However, the RGB led does not glow/fade.